# MailChimp Google Fonts

Tags: fonts, mailchimp, google-fonts

[image]This seems like a simple question with an elusive answer. I am trying to use the Google Font Montserrat for my MailChimp emails. Headers, paragraphs, the whole thing. This font is not a default selection in the MC portal.

I see the HTML code window, but nothing from my research seems to work. Does anyone know how to do this?

I have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14387716/is-it-possible-to-use-google-webfonts-in-a-mailchimp-template) from StackOverflow, but it's over ten years old and does not affect the current MC design portal.

I appreciate any help you can provide.